# PHP Multi-Dimensional Array to CSV

Tags: php, arrays, forms, csv, post

I have a form with multidimensional arrays and single arrays. The multidimensional arrays can by dynamically generated when a user clicks a button so they can add a field like another job, or another degree.

In the case of the multidimensional arrays, I wanted to test to make sure they were collecting data.  I ran the following on my Education Input Collection `print_r($_POST["educationHistory"]` to test the array and make sure it's logging correctly.  It is and it outputs the array content in the following manner:

```
Array ( [0] => WLU [1] => Math [2] => 2016 )
```

and for each array logged after, the numbers change and so on.

When I try and save the multidimensional array to the .CSV it comes out quite differently.

I'm trying to push the above style of the print_r layout `(Array ( [0] => WLU [1] => Math [2] => 2016 ))` to the csv file I am outputting all the form fields to, but I am having no luck.

Is such a thing possible?

I've only gotten as far as being able to print the array values like this(using the above example): WLU Math 2016 but that can get confusing when there are 2 or 3 entries.

Any advice?

Here is the full code:

PHP

```
<?php

//page one inputs

$firstName = $_POST["firstName"];
$lastName = $_POST["lastName"];
$homeAddress = $_POST["homeAddress"];
$homeAddressTwo = $_POST["homeAddressTwo"];
$city = $_POST["city"];
$province = $_POST["province"];
$postalCode = $_POST["postalCode"];
$homePhone = $_POST["homePhone"];
$personalEmail = $_POST["personalEmail"];
$confirmEmail = $_POST["confirmEmail"];
$oectaNumber = $_POST["oectaNumber"];
$memberStatus = $_POST["memberStatus"];
$teacherTraining = $_POST["teacherTraining"];
$teachingYears = $_POST["teachingYears"];


$employmentHistory = $_POST["employmentHistory"];
$employmentHistoryValues = "";

foreach($employmentHistory as $value)
{
    $employmentHistoryValues .= $value . " ||| ";
}

$nonSchoolEmployer = $_POST["nonSchoolEmployer"];
$nonSchoolEmployerValues = "";
foreach($nonSchoolEmployer as $employerValue)
{
    $nonSchoolEmployerValues .= $employerValue . " ||| ";
}


$educationHistoryValues = "";
foreach(print_r($_POST["educationHistory"]) as $educationValue)
{
    $educationHistoryValues .= $educationValue;
}



$csvdata = $firstName . ", " . $lastName . ", " . $homeAddress . ", " . $homeAddressTwo . ", " . $city . ", " . $province . ", " . $postalCode . ", " . $homePhone . ", " . $personalEmail . ", " . $confirmEmail . ", " . $oectaNumber . ", " . $memberStatus . ", " . $teacherTraining . ", " . $teachingYears . "," . $employmentHistoryValues . "," . $nonSchoolEmployerValues . "," . $educationHistoryValues;

$fp = fopen("formdata.csv", "a");

if($fp)
{
    fwrite($fp, $csvdata . "\n");
    fclose($fp);
}

?>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="educationHistory" name="educationHistory[]">
    <input type="text" class="three-lines" name="educationHistory[]" id="educationInstitution_1" placeholder="Institution" onblur="this.placeholder='Institution'" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onkeyup="checkPage2()" />

    <input type="text" class="three-lines" name="educationHistory[]" id="degreeFromInstitution_1" placeholder="Degree/Diploma" onblur="this.placeholder='Degree/Diploma'" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onkeyup="checkPage2()" />

    <input type="date" class="three-lines" name="educationHistory[]" id="educationalDates_1" />
    <input type="button" value="+" onclick="addEducation()" />
</div><!--end educationHistory Div -->                
</div><!--end of education div-->
```

Comment: Well start by showing us what data you are processing

Comment: Then show us what format you want the output to be in

Comment: Then tell us what hourly rate you are offereing

Comment: Ha! At this point, whatever you want! I'm going to amend the question to include the HTML just hang on

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this $_POST data:

```
$_POST['employmentHistory']=array('somehere','somethere');
$_POST['nonSchoolEmployer']=array('somebody','somebodyelse');
$_POST['educationHistory']=array('heapshere','heapsoverthere','andtheretoo');
$_POST['firstName']="John";
$_POST['lastName']="Smith";
$_POST['homeAddress']="1 Here St.";
$_POST['homeAddressTwo']="Apt 2";
$_POST['city']="Townsville";
$_POST['province']="Quebec";
$_POST['postalCode']="H1C";
$_POST['homePhone']="418-555-0157";
$_POST['personalEmail']="418-555-0135";
$_POST['confirmEmail']="js@H1C.ca";
$_POST['oectaNumber']="999999";
$_POST['memberStatus']="Active";
$_POST['teacherTraining']="some";
$_POST['teachingYears']="eleventeen";
```

Here is your code: (I am obligated to warn you that your $_POST data should first be validated/sanitized.)

```
$employmentHistoryValues=implode(' ||| ',$_POST["employmentHistory"]);
// this avoids the trailing ' ||| ' that your method produced.

$nonSchoolEmployerValues=implode(' ||| ',$_POST["nonSchoolEmployer"]);
// this avoids the trailing ' ||| ' that your method produced.

// Your foreach(print_r()) will throw a WARNING and should not be used.
// Your method smashes all $_POST["educationHistory"] data together with no separator, so I will too.
$educationHistoryValues=implode('',$_POST["educationHistory"]);

// declare the keys of the $_POST values you want to extract
$postkeys=array('firstName','lastName','homeAddress','homeAddressTwo','city','province','postalCode','homePhone','personalEmail','confirmEmail','oectaNumber','memberStatus','teacherTraining','teachingYears');

// join the single-value elements with the multi-value elements and glue them together as a comma-space-separated string.
$csvdata=implode(', ',array_merge(array_intersect_key($_POST,array_flip($postkeys)),[$employmentHistoryValues,$nonSchoolEmployerValues,$educationHistoryValues]));

echo "csvdata = $csvdata";  // remove after you verify result as correct

if($fp=fopen("formdata.csv", "a")){
    fwrite($fp,$csvdata."\n");
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Output:

```
csvdata = John, Smith, 1 Here St., Apt 2, Townsville, Quebec, H1C, 418-555-0157, 418-555-0135, js@H1C.ca, 999999, Active, some, eleventeen, somehere ||| somethere, somebody ||| somebodyelse, heapshereheapsoverthereandtheretoo
```

---

**Edit: I just re-read your question and didn't address the form field naming issue**...

If you are trying to batch the educationHistory data in threes, then you can set up your form like this:

```
<input type="text" class="three-lines" name="educationHistory[0][institution]" id="educationInstitution_1" placeholder="Institution" onblur="this.placeholder='Institution'" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onkeyup="checkPage2()" />

<input type="text" class="three-lines" name="educationHistory[0][degree]" id="degreeFromInstitution_1" placeholder="Degree/Diploma" onblur="this.placeholder='Degree/Diploma'" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onkeyup="checkPage2()" />

<input type="date" class="three-lines" name="educationHistory[0][date]" id="educationalDates_1" />
<input type="button" value="+" onclick="addEducation()" />
```

And have `addEducation()` increment the indices on the next batch of fields.

Receiving:

```
$_POST['educationHistory']=array(
    array('institute'=>'WLU','degree'=>'Math','date'=>'2016'),
    array('institute'=>'UQ','degree'=>'English','date'=>'2012')
);
```

Your processing code could then be:

```
$educationHistoryValues='';
foreach($_POST['educationHistory'] as $a){
    $educationHistoryValues.=($educationHistoryValues!=''?', ':'').implode(' ',$a);
}

echo "educationHistoryValues = $educationHistoryValues";
//    educationHistoryValues = WLU Math 2016, UQ English 2012
```